# Create data frame from list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame (`mydata`) with >200 variables. I would like to automatically subset some of them into a smaller data frame.

The name of the variables I would like to subset follow a naming convention, e.g., `"Q1Pct", "Q2Pct", ... "Q18Pct"`.

I can get a list of the variables using:

```
Q.names <- setNames(as.list(1:18),paste(paste0("mydata$Q",1:18,"Pct")))
```

I have tried to combine the list into a new data frame, but it isn't working:

```
df.QList <- data.frame(Q.names)
```

I'm sure there is a much better way to do this - please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
library(dplyr)

select(mydata, all_of(paste0("Q",1:18,"Pct")))
```

Or, more simply (base R):

```
mydata[,paste0("Q",1:18,"Pct")]
```

Comment: Thank you so much langtang - you're a legend! That works perfectly!